# Assembly x86, How to write binary to file as an integer

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm really new to assembly and currently writing a program that obtains an integer from user input using [Irvine32](http://csc.csudh.edu/mmccullough/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Freadint.htm) lib's `ReadInt`which saves the value as a binary. Now I need to write this binary value as an integer to a file. This file has already been created.

From research, I need to convert this binary value to a integer string. But I really not sure how to achieve this.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
idPromptStr byte "Please enter ID (Must between 0 and 30) : ", 13, 10, 0
id DWORD ? 
filename BYTE "userinfo.txt",0, 0Dh, 0Ah
fileHandle DWORD ?
bytesWritten DWORD ?
.code
main proc
    INVOKE      GetID
    INVOKE      WriteUserInfoToFile
    exit
main endp

GetID PROC
    ; Obtain ID from input
    mov     edx,OFFSET idPromptStr
    call    WriteString
    call    ReadInt ;Reads the integer value from console and moves it to eax.
    mov     id,eax ;Input value is taken in eax. 
GetID ENDP

WriteUserInfoToFile PROC
    ;write ID to file
    writeId:
        mov     eax,fileHandle
        mov     edx,OFFSET id
        mov     ecx,4
        call    WriteToFile ;this doesn't work
        jc      showErrorMsg
        mov     edx, eax
        call    WriteInt
        mov     bytesWritten,eax
        INVOKE  WriteCarriageReturn
WriteUserInfoToFile ENDP
end main
```

I have removed input validation and other code from this snippet so it's easier to read. But I use the same writing method to write other string to the same file and it works well for other string variable.

Comment: Are you allowed to write the equivalent code in C in some `spir.c` file, to use the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler as `gcc -fverbose-asm -S -O2 spir.c` on that C file, and to look inside the generated `spir.s` assembler file? Did you read the [*Application Binary Interface*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specification relevant to your processor and operating system? For Linux/x86-64 it is [here](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf) and you need to find the equivalent for your OS and processor

Comment: everything must be in pure assembly, unfortunately. I'm currently trying to process the source code of the Irvine32 WriteInt procedure. It converts the binary to int and print it to console. But I'm simply stuck..

[Irvine32 WriteInt](https://github.com/mysteriouspants/SlopBukkit/blob/master/CS118/examples/Lib32/Irvine32_Library/Irvine32.asm)

Comment: BTW, why do you code assembler in 2021. Any good enough compiler will generate better code than what you reasonably can write ! See also [OSDEV](https://osdev.org/)

Comment: I'm learning assembly for reverse engineering

Comment: Then you need to look into projects like [BINSEC](https://binsec.github.io/) - developed by colleagues from [CEA LIST](http://www-list.cea.fr), and you need to study [*Operational Semantics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_semantics) and probably [*Abstract Interpretation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation). Check also with your lawyer: in some countries, reverse engineering of binary software could be illegal. A good alternative is of course to use [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) software (like Linux)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by adapting the Irvine32 `WriteInt` procedure. Modification occurs in the last jump, it writes the string to file instead of calling `WriteString` at the end

Comment: Doesn't WriteString take a pointer to a 0-terminated string?  If you want to write exactly 4 bytes, you need none of  them to be `0x00`, and for there to be a 5th byte after (with value `0`).  Very likely you should be using `WriteToFile` with a pointer and length.